# Can not build the third party in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

After install react-native-navigation, I want to rebuild it. The build failed.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6.
>   Required by:
>         project :app > project :react-native-navigation
>   Could not resolve com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.6.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation/2.0.6/ahbottomnavigation-2.0.6.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/74.125.24.93, dl.google.com/74.125.24.136, dl.google.com/74.125.24.91, dl.google.com/74.125.24.190] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4.
>     Required by:
>         project :app > project :react-native-navigation
>   Could not resolve com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.5.4.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/balysv/materialmenu/material-menu-toolbar/1.5.4/material-menu-toolbar-1.5.4.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/74.125.24.93, dl.google.com/74.125.24.136, dl.google.com/74.125.24.91, dl.google.com/74.125.24.190] failed: Connection timed out: connect

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 32s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I haven't change anything in build.gradle. Thanks in advance

Comment: in my case cleaning the build helps most of the times! =>  cd android && ./gradlew --info clean && cd .. and then rebuild => react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the respond, but the problem is my office connections that has proxy in it. When i change connection to use my own wifi, it works!